# Error while creating a simple barcode scanner for android JellyBean OS

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, zxing, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am new to android application development. I am developing a simple barcode scanner application by using Zxing. I am using the latest ADT and I am developing under Eclipse.

Below are my codes:

```
package com.example.test_app2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String SCAN_RESULT = "com.example.Test_App2.RESULT";
DisplayScanResultActivity disp = new DisplayScanResultActivity();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
    }

    public void scanBarcode(View view)
    {
       IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);
    }
}
```

This is the MainActivity class.

```
package com.example.test_app2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class DisplayScanResultActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_scan_result);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_scan_result, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:

        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE: {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
    requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (scanResult != null) {
    String upc = scanResult.getContents();

    // put whatever you want to do with the code here
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(upc);
    setContentView(tv);
    }
    }
    break;
    }
    }
    }
```

This is the activity which shows the scan result. But I am not able to understand how can I show the scan result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test_app2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test_app2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test_app2.DisplayScanResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_scan_result"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.Test_App2.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.Test_App2.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is AndroidManifest.xml file.

[image]

When I run this project through emulator the scan button gets displayed. As soon as I click it, the application crashes. How can I solve this? Please help me find a solution.

Comment: I have used the Zxing IntentIntegrator and IntentResult under the same package i.e, "package com.example.barcode_scanner". But the problem still persists.

Comment: In Android you don't get the log in the console, you need to open the LogCat view in Eclipse. There you see detailed information and your stack trace of your crash. So please post the stack trace you find there, not the console content (unrelated to this issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confused approach. You appear to be wanting to integrate with Barcode Scanner by Intent, but then you are sort of declaring our activity and namespace in your app, where it doesn't exist.

Throw all that away and just do this: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: thanks for the help.Let me try the new approach you suggested.I will also try to test using webcam and reply you back whether manage to get success.

Comment: I'm not getting it. Correct me if I am wrong. IntentIntegrator and IntentResult, these two classes are used like a library which contains certain methods that handles certain scan functionalities. So, if I am integrating those two classes to my application then there is no need to install the existing barcode scanner app? right? But when I am running my application it's prompting to install the existing app. Why?

Comment: Also, please explicitly mention which namespaces that I was using, you were talking about..

Comment: You use those two classes to call to Barcode Scanner, a separate app. Surely you see in the manifest you posted that you are declaring your app as if it were ours: `com.google.zxing.client.android`. Do *not* do that.

Comment: So, if I use those two classes then I have to create a separate activity where I should put the onActivityResult() method to handle the result, other than MainActivity and I need to pass that separate activity as a parameter to the IntentIntegrator constructor?

Comment: Yes, there is at least your app which does whatever you need to do with the scan. It is the thing which starts the Intent.

Comment: Okay, thanks for assisting. Now I need to know how can I show the scan result? I am using the webcam solution you mentioned above. But I am not being able to write the code to handle the task as I've no experience in developing android apps. This is my first approach. If you show me some code sample to handle the scan result it would be very helpful. I have also modified my question above. Please see.